# OnCollisionEnter unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a trouble with a collision, i know this is not the way to do "bullets" , but for now im very new and I'm exploring and trying some stuff. I have in my little "bullet" a script with the "onCollisionEnter" function, but when i shoot to make the cube dissapear I have to take 2 shots(two fasts) instead one to that occur, and i do not understand why.
my code says:

```
   void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Cube")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);

        }
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name);


    }
```

[VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YN1wuhyroT4)

THANKS!

Comment: What components does the cube have?

Comment: that bullet have any collider ?

Comment: if its collision enabled like is_triggered unchecked then how the bullet can pass through the cube first check that both objects have collider and bullet should have rigid body and cube.
second thing is that  is your rigid body check on the continuous  collision detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here two things you need to check for the collision to work properly in Unity3D.

**1. The two objects that are being collided in your case the bullet and the cube that the bullet is gonna collide with should have a collider (box or capsule) anything. And make sure isTrigger is off.**

**2. This is very important. Either one of the gameObject i.e., your bullet or the cube should have rigidbody component for collision to actually take place. If you dont have a rigidbody in the one of the components your collision wont work. So, I would suggest you to add rigidbody component to your bullet and that should do the magic for you.**

Let me know if these worked or if you have any other problem.

And to which gameObject have you attached the following script to?